How to handle saturated hot air at the inlet of a blower
I have hot (around 60°C) saturated air entering a side channel blower.
Due to process constraints, I can't use a condenser or air dryer (such as desiccant) at the blower inlet.
However, water vapor condensation inside the blower might be an issue.
Should I be concerned, and what solutions are available?
I am curious about how some vacuum pumps that extract vapor, as well as some blowers that operate in hot, humid conditions, function.

Any time you are dealing with saturated air and need to prevent condensation you can do one of three things:

Remove the water (but as you stated this is not an option in this case).
Increase the temperature. Warmer air stores more water and thus would no longer be saturated. (temperature above the dew point)
Decrease the pressure. Lower pressure air stores more water vapor. (The reason compressed air systems require condensate drains)

It is doubtful you will have any condensation in the blower during steady state. A side channel blower (also called a regenerative blower) is not particularly efficient and generates a lot of heat on the rotor and housing; this increase in temperature will keep water from condensing. There will be an increase in pressure, but probably not enough to overcome the temperate increase.
To be sure there is never any condensation even during startup conditions you will need to add a heater to the inlet, blower casing, and discharge line. Probably overkill if you are just worried about corrosion, but if the air has small amounts of particulate that could adhere in the presence of moisture, you will need to make certain it does not condense under any circumstances.

Is it possible to ignore vapor and just grain the condensate by inclining the blower (maybe 10 degrees)? is is a good idea?

I was checking the systems and processes that handle hot humid air in the papers, I came across this paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.enconman.2022.115369. I am really wondering how the blower of this system works. the inlet hot and maybe saturated air incident with the wall of the blower, which is most likely colder. I think they have water condensation.

check the images of the mentioned paper here:
https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0196890422001650-gr4.jpg
https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0196890422001650-gr2.jpg

I will need some more context on what you are trying to do. Is it closed loop, are there other chemicals, how often is it services, etc. The blower will run just fine with some condensation and mist if that is your worry. It is not like a high speed turbine that will tear itself apart. The main reason to avoid condensation in this case is to reduce corrosion, damage to bearings, and avoid particulate build up due to adhesion.

Thank you for your answer. I plan to operate it 24/7. You think that will be okay? If we consider the blower in that paper, will that operate fine?

In the future, can I have a better alternative to side channel blowers for achieving a 12 kPa pressure increase to blow 60°C saturated air?

An engineer uses the context of the system to determine additional things like failure modes, if people will be injured if it fails, etc. If you ask an easy equation based question we can answer it without context, but if you ask a complicated question you need to provide as many details about your project as possible to permit a good answer.
